# Can't change the JDK Location , whenever i change the location of JDK it use embedded JDK

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle

hello i have just installed android studio 3.0 and am facing 2 problems now , that i Can't change the JDK Location , whenever i change the location of JDK it use embedded JDK

```
Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher
```

they told me that this error because of the JDk location

thanks in advance
pics:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m08If.png)

also as i said before that the design and layout isn't working picture:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6lyu.png)

Comment: Can you copy/paste the error into the post so it's easy to search/read through?

Comment: @mac9416 done . . ..

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that you downloaded a 32bit or 64bit version of one of the tools, but your operating system is the opposite.

So if you are running 64bit Windows.
then you need to ensure you have 64bit JRE and JDK and 64 bit Android Studio.

That will fix your issue.

Comment: i am using android studio 32 , jdk 32 , win32

Comment: Is your OS 32bit for sure and how about your JDK pointer in Android Studio is it pointed to the 32 bit version